# Gemfile error when deploying GitHub repo to Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, jekyll

I'm trying to push my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/citrusui/citrusui.github.io) to Heroku.

Apparently my Gemfile is incorrect. I've checked it twice, and find no typos or anything, but it complains about rb-inotify being added and removed.

Here's the log:

```
Ruby app detected
Compiling Ruby
Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
      Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
      You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
      your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
      updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
      You have added to the Gemfile:
      * rb-inotify
      You have deleted from the Gemfile:
      * rb-inotify
      Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
      your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
      updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

      You have added to the Gemfile:
      * rb-inotify

      You have deleted from the Gemfile:
      * rb-inotify
!
!     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
!
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Comment: Please, whenever possible put the content of your question **in** your question and not as links to volatile external resources.

Comment: Fixed. The formatting looks awful though.

Comment: Does the "You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing your Gemfile." part help any?

Comment: No, and I'm not sure what it entails.

Comment: You could try removing `Gemfile.lock`, then run `bundle install` again. Push in the corrected version.

Comment: "The formatting looks awful though." [Stack Overflow provides help for editing boxes.](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) Look at the top of the box or try clicking the little `?` in the corner.

Comment: I don't understand..  If you're using bundler, which is a dependency manager, why would you require both `gh-pages` and `jekyll` dependencies in the `Gemfile`? The other thing is, why are you running `bundle install --without ` if you don't have any groups set in the Gemfile? Anyway, if the problem is with the gem `rb-inotify`, how about removing it from Gemfile? If it is a dependency of another gem, bundler will install it anyway. Just my thoughts... Hope to have helped ;)

Comment: I've just got the same error (locally). Run `bundle update` and see if it fixes yours too.